# Adding multiple images to ShareDialog

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Using the **Facebook Android SDK**, How can I add multiple images by URL into my custom FB opengraph story? I'm following the example on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/android
but it doesn't show a way for multiple images.

I don't have a website to scrape.

NOTE:
This question is explicitly about how to do this with Android's Facebook SDK. This is clearly another question as the marked duplicate, which is about [how to share pictures using the API in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015640/how-do-i-can-post-a-multiple-photos-via-facebook-api)

Comment: @luschn Duplicate? From which one?

Comment: there is a link on top of your question to the other question. how to post multiple images at once has been asked a lot of times already.

Comment: @luschn  See edit. This is explicitly about android SDK. How can you mark this as duplicate? I'm almost regretting tagging this facebook-graph-api....I've untagged it so you can't harm it any further.

Comment: it´s about the graph api in general, the android sdk uses the graph api. it is exactly the same issue.

Comment: @luschn, with your reasoning everything on SO is a dup as all questions are about programming... Making a wallpost with pictures from the album is something totally different than doing a share from an app with custom og fields and external content. There is no documentation about for example how to use the caption fields in the FB OpenGraph console. I hoped for some people here to help me find it out but you killed that opportunity directly. Really sad!

Comment: sorry if you see it that way. i can tell you that what you want to achieve is not possible. you should consider adding more information to your questions in the future though, this was way too broad from the beginning anyway. (for example: what have you tried so far?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117175/discussion-between-pepster-and-luschn).