# New Facebook post doesn't show associated images

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using FB GraphAPI to first upload some images to FB. Images are uploaded okay. By intention, I am not showing these images on the timeline by setting the `'no_story' => true` as one of the parameters of the request. The endpoint for these image uploads is `/me/photos`. From the responses, I can get the IDs of the images. I get them into an array:

```
$imgIds = array(
    'attached_media[0]' => '{"media_fbid":"1323254207729699"}',
    'attached_media[1]' => '{"media_fbid":"1323254211063032"}',
    'attached_media[2]' => '{"media_fbid":"1323254204396366"}',
    'attached_media[3]' => '{"media_fbid":"1323254201063033"}'
);
```

Next, I am creating a new post on my feed using endpoint `/me/feed` and associate the uploaded images. The post is created on my timeline but the images are not showing up. I followed the example shown at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads and my own code for this post request is below:

```
$params = array(
    "access_token" => $pgAccessToken,
    "message" => "A new post ...",
    "link" => "http://someurl.com",
    "name" => "Title of the post",
    "caption" => "This is the caption",
    "description" => "Some intro text ...",
    "published" => true
);
$params = array_merge($params, $imgIds);
$rsp = $fb->post("/me/feed", $params);
```

**EDIT**

FB doc says `Currently we support publishing multi-photo posts for a User only.`
I am using a page access token, not a user access token. I guess this may be the issue. When I tried with a user access token, the post did not appear on the timeline. Need to check token settings.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the images arent show up" with the post

Comment: The post contains the caption, title and description but not the photos.

Comment: With user token, the post appears on the user's timeline, not on the timeline of a page the user manages. So I have to use page access token, which does not permit multi-photo post!

Comment: This might help https://forum.hootsuite.com/discussion/6604437/posting-one-message-with-multiple-images-to-facebook I have not used the API but it seems that you must select an album before posting, might work if FB pages supports albums too.

Comment: Seems like aui (albumid) is depreciated https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos