# Is it possible to upload an image to my own Facebook group via FB Group API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, file-upload

I have a Facebook group that I manage and I want to use the Facebook groups API to post some images automatically from my server, at the moment I use the `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{group-id}/feed` endpoint to upload text and links to the group but I want to be able to publish an image as well (multiple images would be best), but I don't understand if it's possible or not, it seems like Meta API docs point to the [group photos API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/photos) but it is not clear how to use it I can't find the body param where I should provide the image URL/base64 to, there's only `aid` (album id) which is deprecated.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [url](https://developers.facebook.com/micro_site/url/?click_from_context_menu=true&country=IN&destination=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fgraph-api%2Freference%2Fgroup%2Fphotos%23parameters&event_type=click&last_nav_impression_id=0bNkMlysnyI0b0UZI&max_percent_page_viewed=79&max_viewport_height_px=567&max_viewport_width_px=1280&orig_http_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fgraph-api%2Freference%2Fgroup%2Fphotos&orig_request_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fajax%2Fdocs%2Fnav%2F%3Fpath1%3Dgraph-api%26path2%3Dreference%26path3%3Dgroup%26path4%3Dphotos&region=apac&scrolled=true&session_id=1uDcQtpglhmbovIT9&site=developers) Param of Group Photos API to specify the image file.

Example request:-

```json
curl -i -X POST \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/222863893908133/photos?url=https%3A%2F%2Fimg.freepik.com%2Ffree-photo%2Fwide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg&access_token=EAAOPZAhS8Nx4BAHP4gGZXXX"
```

Response:-

```json
{
  "id": "571144611858970",
  "post_id": "222863893908133_222867323907790"
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you it works! Do you know how can I post multiple images in the same post?

Comment: @123, Glad it works for you :). I am not sure about posting multiple images as I haven't tried it yet but you may find this useful:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015640/how-do-i-can-post-a-multiple-photos-via-facebook-api